# Issues with make jQuery ajax call to a rest api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use jquery ajax to make a post request that returns some response but it does not seem to work properly. Sometimes it works after a long wait, other times it does not work at all.This is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

const id =  $('#auth').val();
  $("#set").click(function(){
    $('.spinner-grow').show();

  $.post("https://ravesandboxapi.flutterwave.com/v2/gpx/transactions/escrow/settle",
  {
    id: id,
    secret_key: "FLWSECK-25*******************0628-X"
  },

  function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    $('.spinner-grow').hide();
  });
});


</script>
```

what might be the issue here?

Comment: Open developer console (`F12`). What do you see in the Network tab when it "does not work at all"?

Comment: ````Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)```` but there is no problem with it working with postman or codepunker

Comment: Is there any `body` coming back with that error? For example, many endpoints return `404` if the entity you're trying to access does not exist; perhaps your `id` is incorrect. Or, it can mean that the URL is incorrect. And are you sure that the endpoint is a `POST`?

Comment: yes, i just saw this ````jquery.min.js:4 POST https://ravesandboxapi.flutterwave.com/v2/gpx/transactions/escrow/settle 400 (Bad Request)````

Comment: A `400 Bad Request` means that you've sent bad data - either it was malformed, or the data was wrong. Confirm that your "Request" body was what you expect.

Comment: Well i think my problem is with the way i am getting the id from the form ````const id =  $('#auth').val();````. I inserted the value directly in the code and it worked

Comment: Without HTML we can't really help with that unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

The following is a complete example of a AJAX post is handled via jQuery. Just sharing it for reference.

```
    var url = "api/path/to/your/controller";
    var data = {};
    data.id = id;
    data.secret = 'your-secret';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function (resultObject) {
            console.log(resultObject);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log('An error occured');
        }
    });
```

If you are getting a 404 error, better check the path to the API. You can use a tool like Postman to validate your requests and then try implementing the same in code.

Also make sure that there is no CORS issue as from your code we cannot understand if your post is triggered from the same domain.

Comment: While this is helpful, it isn't an *answer*. Suggestions, requests for more information, guesses, etc, should be *comments*. If you need to include code alongside a comment, consider an external resouce (JSFiddle, etc).